# Excel VBA, Select statement changes after Execute

Tags: sql, oracle, vba, excel

So I'm having an issue where any long string I try to set as a SQL query returns an error when trying to copy from the recordset into Excel

For example, if i use a query like this

```
select 
cdf.DAY_STAMP Day, b.ACCOUNT_NUMBER Acct#, cdf.CM_DESC MAC, 
b.STREET_NUMBER St#, b.STREET_NAME StName, b.CITY City,
b.TRANSPORT_ELEMENT_2 census,
i.ifalias node,
cdf.SUM_BYTES_UP, cdf.SUM_BYTES_DOWN, cdf.SUM_RESET_COUNT, cdf.AVG_TXPOWER_UP,
cdf.MAX_TXPOWER_UP, cdf.MIN_TXPOWER_UP, cdf.AVG_RXPOWER_DOWN, cdf.MAX_RXPOWER_DOWN,
cdf.MIN_RXPOWER_DOWN, cdf.AVG_RXPOWER_UP, cdf.MAX_RXPOWER_UP, cdf.MIN_RXPOWER_UP,
cdf.AVG_PATH_LOSS_UP, cdf.AVG_CER_DOWN, cdf.MAX_CER_DOWN, cdf.MIN_CER_DOWN,
cdf.AVG_CCER_DOWN, cdf.MAX_CCER_DOWN, cdf.MIN_CCER_DOWN, cdf.AVG_SNR_DOWN,
cdf.MAX_SNR_DOWN, cdf.MIN_SNR_DOWN, cdf.US_CER_MAX, cdf.US_CCER_MAX, cdf.US_SNR_MIN,
cdf.STATUS_VALUE_MIN, cdf.TIMING_OFFSET_LAST, cdf.ROWCOUNT, cdf.T3_TIMEOUTS,
cdf.T4_TIMEOUTS, cdf.SYSUPTIME
from cm_day_facts cdf
inner join int_attributes i 
on i.ifalias like '72F007%' and i.topologyid = cdf.up_id
inner join billing_data b
on b.equipment_mac = cdf.cm_desc
where cdf.DAY_stamp >= '12-MAY-12 00:00'
```

I get an ERROR: Operation is not allowed when the object is closed

But if I use a query like: Select * from "DWRVWR"."CSOC_M_WIPMASTER"

I get a valid response with no issues.

.

Full code:

```
Sub CableData_SQLconn()

'Connect to Oracle server begin
Set sqlCon = New ADODB.Connection
Set sqlCommand = New ADODB.Command
Set sqlRecordSet = New ADODB.Recordset
Dim Conn As String
Dim sqlQuery As String
Dim sqlQuery2 As String
Dim sqlQuery3 As String

'grab node from user input box
node = InputBox("Node")

'Connection string
Conn = "Provider=MSDASQL; Driver={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle}; " & _
    "CONNECTSTRING=(DESCRIPTION=" & "(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)" & _ 
    "(HOST=myhost)(PORT=myport))" & "(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=mysid))); uid=user; pwd=pass;"

'Build SQL Query
sqlQuery = "A REALLY LONG STRING"
sqlQuery2 = sqlQuery & "A REALLY LONG STRING"
sqlQuery3 = sqlQuery2 & "A REALLY LONG STRING"

'This output is confirmed to have the full query - **VERIFIED OUTPUT IS CORRECT**
Range("A1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = sqlQuery3

'---------------------------------------------------------------
' Set file details for SQL query
fileDir = "C:\temp\"
filePath = "C:\temp\" & node & "_SRO_TCs.sql"

'check if directory exists, if not create it
If Dir(fileDir, cbDirectory) = "" Then
MkDir fileDir
End If

' open the file output
Open filePath For Output As #1

'Write full SQL query to file - VERIFIED
outputText = sqlQuery3
Print #1, outputText
'-----------------------------------------------------------    


'open connection
sqlCon.ConnectionString = Conn
  'Cn.CursorLocation = adUseClient
sqlCon.Open

'set and execute sql command
Set sqlCommand.ActiveConnection = sqlCon
sqlCommand.CommandText = sqlQuery3
sqlCommand.CommandType = adCmdText
sqlCommand.Execute sqlQuery3

'open recordset
Set sqlRecordSet.ActiveConnection = sqlCon
sqlRecordSet.Open sqlCommand

'copy data to excel
'ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset (sqlRecordSet)
If Not sqlRecordSet.EOF Then    '<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< ERROR: Operation is not allowed when the object is closed
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset sqlRecordSet
Else: MsgBox "No records returned!"
End If

'close connections
sqlRecordSet.Close
sqlCon.Close

'Close file
Close #1

End Sub
```

Comment: How long is your string?  I have had problems with ado queries longer than 8k.

Comment: @GordonLinoff the string is very long... 30k characters... how can i circumvent this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Convert your query to a stored procedure with whatever parameters you want, then call the stored procedure from Excel and paste the results in your workbook. In the example I've listed below, I'm connecting to SQL Server, but it will work the same if you are connecting to Oracle.

Here's some code you can modify to work with your application:

```
    Public Sub RunStoredProcedureFromExcel()
    Dim rsData As ADODB.Recordset

    Dim ProductID, CategoryID, StoreNumber As Integer
    ProductID = Sheets("Variables").Range("nrProductID").Value
    CategoryID = Sheets("Variables").Range("nrCategoryID").Value
    StoreNumber = Sheets("Variables").Range("nrSelectedStore").Value

    ' Clear the destination worksheet
    Sheet39.UsedRange.Clear

    ' Set the ADODB Connection
    ConnectToSQLServer

    ' Create the Recordset object.
    Set rsData = New ADODB.Recordset

    ' Open the pooled connection
    mcnSQLServer.Open
    mcnSQLServer.espGetLookupData ProductID, CategoryID, StoreNumber, rsData

    If Not rsData.EOF Then

        ' Paste the results into workbook
        Sheet39.Range("a1").CopyFromRecordset rsData

    Else
        MsgBox "No data located.", vbCritical, "Error!"
    End If

    ' Close the pooled connection
    mcnSQLServer.Close

    End Sub
```

There is a great chapter on this topic in the book [Professional Excel Development](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321508793) which was the starting point for the code above.